# Meaning of "making a point to..."

Tags: meaning, translation

I have a translation problem, and maybe somebody can help me with this.

After someone had said a stupid sentence, I heard somebody reply:

> Well, he was making a point, I guess, to some distant star.

I'm almost sure this was some kind of insult, but I'm just not able to translate it, or to really understand the meaning of this expression.

Comment: It is not an expression in general use. You're right to think of it as a mild insult, or sarcasm. I would interpret the metaphor as saying that the  point was argued in an abstract and metaphysical manner.  Not "stupid" but vaguely and obtusely.

Comment: In a general sense, it's something like "I might as well be talking to the wall." when someone is not paying attention to or interested in what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this. One is "he was making a point". This phrase is commonly used after someone argues a point that does not really matter. It is to say that someone cares more about making their point than they do about giving useful information.

"To some distant star" is not a common way to end that sentence. But I suspect it is to emphasize that the point the person was trying to make had no relevance to the people he was speaking to. Possibly, the person did not even care if the people around him understood (as if he was 'talking to a star').